# Want to Add 2 columns dollar sign

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 columns(Col1 and Col2) in tab1  in snowflake mentioned below
Col1 : $10,
Col2 : $25

I want to add the 2 columns

Select sum(Col1+Col2) as Amt from tab1 ;

But i am facing the error :
Numeric value '$25.00' is not recognized

Please advise how i can add these 2 columns in snowflake and get the result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So because you have the dollar sign saved in the columns, they are maybe of datatype varchar2, but especially they are not of datatype number.
You can't make calculations on varchar2 columns if there are non-numeric characters in the data, so you must get rid of the dollar signs and convert the varchar2-data to numbers, for example like this:

```
    Select sum(to_number(replace(Col1,'$','')) + to_number(replace(Col2,'$',''))) as Amt from tab1;
```

Better way would be to save the dollar amounts (without the dollar sign) in columns that have numeric datatype, but if that can't be changed then you must change the data to be numeric before making any calculations with it.